# Edit CSV-Files with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm very new to Python and programming in general, so please explain it simply.
I tried to change a CSV file, but I always get an error, how can I fix it?

Code:

````
import pandas as pd

with pd.read_csv ('D: \ P \ Python projects \ correct CSV \ test.csv') as file

if "\\" in file:
betterfile = file.replace ("\\", "/")
print (betterfile)```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ lib \ runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code (code, main_globals, None,
File "C: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ lib \ runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec (code, run_globals)
File "c: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ .vscode \ extensions \ ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595 \ pythonFiles \ lib \ python \ debugpy \ __ main__.py", line 45, in <module>
cli.main ()
File "c: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ .vscode \ extensions \ ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595 \ pythonFiles \ lib \ python \ debugpy / .. \ debugpy \ server \ cli.py", line 444, in main
run()
File "c: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ .vscode \ extensions \ ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595 \ pythonFiles \ lib \ python \ debugpy / .. \ debugpy \ server \ cli.py", line 285, in run_file
runpy.run_path (target_as_str, run_name = compat.force_str ("__ main__"))
File "C: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ lib \ runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
code, fname = _get_code_from_file (run_name, path_name)
File "C: \ Users \ Vinstand YT \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ lib \ runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
code = compile (f.read (), fname, 'exec')
File "d: \ P \ Python Projects \ Correct CSV \ Project CSV corrector.py", line 3
with pd.read_csv ('D: \ P \ Python Projects \ Correct CSV \ test.csv') as file
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
````

Comment: "import Pandas as pd" is missing in code

Comment: You cannot use `pd.read_csv` and `with`. `pd.read_csv` returns a dataframe whereas `with` gives you a context managed view of the file. Take a look at the [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) tutorial, specifically the "Getting data in/out" section.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two different ways of reading csv files.

1. `pd.read_csv`
2. `open`

`pd.read_csv` is used to read a file to a `pandas.DataFrame`

For your purpose, you can stick to using `open`:

```
with open('D:\P\Python projects\correct CSV \test.csv') as file:
    contents = file.read()
if "\\" in contents:
    betterfile = file.replace("\\", "/")
```